# regex remove whitespaces and match exact words

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

I'm don't know regex really well, so can someone give me example how to fix this regex http://rubular.com/r/UdzYMJc9iE:

```
/\b([stack over flow]+)+\b/
```

not to match whitespaces and to match only exact words (stack matches ac as word, I want to match only stack), tia.

I want when we have 'lorem etiam nam' to match only these exact 3 words from the regex, without spaces.

I tried using \s, \S, /x, but there was no result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to match three alternatives, use the `|` syntax, and group them into normal parenthesis:

```
 /\b(stack|over|flow)+\b/
```

Not sure about the `+` or what exactly you wanted to match.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all words, not any in particular, `\b(\w+)+\b` should work.

Comment: Sorry for answering the wrong question ;) Looks like you got your answer anwyay.

Answer (score 1):

I use this website if I need some help with RegEx: http://www.txt2re.com/

It is really useful as I don't need RegEx that often. And it is perfect for the occasional use.

To check the expression, and to refine it I then use http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ also a very good tool.

And I think you would want something like:

```
(word|second|third)+
```